# Basic Programming in R - How to build a sequence with pattern?

Tags: r, plot, sequence

I want to build a sequence of the type `a(n)=a(a(n-1))+a(n-a(n-1))` with `a(1)=a(2)=1` and length `n=200`, and then construct the plot of `a(n)/n`. Any ideas?

Comment: With a loop? : `?"for"`

Comment: Hi Roman! I see that you are new here, so let me point out that if one of the answers below solved your issue, you can accept the answer by clicking on the `v` sign next to the start of the answer. This way the person earns credit and others can see that the issue has been resolved. If your issue wasn't resolved, feel free to specify what is still wrong to enable us to help appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

You use a for loop like this:

```
a <- rep(0,200)
a[1] <- 1
a[2] <- 1
for (n in 3:200) {
  a[n] <- a[a[n-1]] + a[n - a[n-1]]
}

b <- a
for (n in 1:200) {
  b[n] <- a[n]/n
}
```

Result:

```
> a
  [1]   1   1   2   2   3   4   4   4   5   6   7   7   8   8   8   8   9  10  11  12  12  13  14  14  15  15  15  16  16  16  16  16  17  18  19  20  21  21  22  23  24  24  25  26
 [45]  26  27  27  27  28  29  29  30  30  30  31  31  31  31  32  32  32  32  32  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  38  39  40  41  42  42  43  44  45  45  46  47  47  48  48  48  49  50
 [89]  51  51  52  53  53  54  54  54  55  56  56  57  57  57  58  58  58  58  59  60  60  61  61  61  62  62  62  62  63  63  63  63  63  64  64  64  64  64  64  64  65  66  67  68
[133]  69  70  71  71  72  73  74  75  76  76  77  78  79  80  80  81  82  83  83  84  85  85  86  86  86  87  88  89  90  90  91  92  93  93  94  95  95  96  96  96  97  98  99  99
[177] 100 101 101 102 102 102 103 104 104 105 105 105 106 106 106 106 107 108 109 109 110 111 111 112

> b
  [1] 1.0000000 0.5000000 0.6666667 0.5000000 0.6000000 0.6666667 0.5714286 0.5000000 0.5555556 0.6000000 0.6363636 0.5833333 0.6153846 0.5714286 0.5333333 0.5000000 0.5294118
 [18] 0.5555556 0.5789474 0.6000000 0.5714286 0.5909091 0.6086957 0.5833333 0.6000000 0.5769231 0.5555556 0.5714286 0.5517241 0.5333333 0.5161290 0.5000000 0.5151515 0.5294118
 [35] 0.5428571 0.5555556 0.5675676 0.5526316 0.5641026 0.5750000 0.5853659 0.5714286 0.5813953 0.5909091 0.5777778 0.5869565 0.5744681 0.5625000 0.5714286 0.5800000 0.5686275
 [52] 0.5769231 0.5660377 0.5555556 0.5636364 0.5535714 0.5438596 0.5344828 0.5423729 0.5333333 0.5245902 0.5161290 0.5079365 0.5000000 0.5076923 0.5151515 0.5223881 0.5294118
 [69] 0.5362319 0.5428571 0.5352113 0.5416667 0.5479452 0.5540541 0.5600000 0.5526316 0.5584416 0.5641026 0.5696203 0.5625000 0.5679012 0.5731707 0.5662651 0.5714286 0.5647059
 [86] 0.5581395 0.5632184 0.5681818 0.5730337 0.5666667 0.5714286 0.5760870 0.5698925 0.5744681 0.5684211 0.5625000 0.5670103 0.5714286 0.5656566 0.5700000 0.5643564 0.5588235
[103] 0.5631068 0.5576923 0.5523810 0.5471698 0.5514019 0.5555556 0.5504587 0.5545455 0.5495495 0.5446429 0.5486726 0.5438596 0.5391304 0.5344828 0.5384615 0.5338983 0.5294118
[120] 0.5250000 0.5206612 0.5245902 0.5203252 0.5161290 0.5120000 0.5079365 0.5039370 0.5000000 0.5038760 0.5076923 0.5114504 0.5151515 0.5187970 0.5223881 0.5259259 0.5220588
[137] 0.5255474 0.5289855 0.5323741 0.5357143 0.5390071 0.5352113 0.5384615 0.5416667 0.5448276 0.5479452 0.5442177 0.5472973 0.5503356 0.5533333 0.5496689 0.5526316 0.5555556
[154] 0.5519481 0.5548387 0.5512821 0.5477707 0.5506329 0.5534591 0.5562500 0.5590062 0.5555556 0.5582822 0.5609756 0.5636364 0.5602410 0.5628743 0.5654762 0.5621302 0.5647059
[171] 0.5614035 0.5581395 0.5606936 0.5632184 0.5657143 0.5625000 0.5649718 0.5674157 0.5642458 0.5666667 0.5635359 0.5604396 0.5628415 0.5652174 0.5621622 0.5645161 0.5614973
[188] 0.5585106 0.5608466 0.5578947 0.5549738 0.5520833 0.5544041 0.5567010 0.5589744 0.5561224 0.5583756 0.5606061 0.5577889 0.5600000
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness, you could also write a recursive function. For instance,

```
afun <- function(n){
  if(n < 3) out = 1 
  if(n > 2) out = afun( afun(n-1) ) + afun(n-afun(n-1))
  out
  }
```

I do not claim that this is efficient / better than the loops, though.

Comment: I haven't tested its efficiency, but IMHO this recursive code looks cleaner than a loop. In many cases, the structure of a code can be more important than its performance.

Comment: The efficiency could probably be improved with saving values that otherwise get computed repeatedly. It would also be interesting to see how much gain an `Rcpp` solution would bring. See e.g. http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/blog/2011/09/08/ However, in the current version, it is not very efficient, though I have not checked the loops.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop, like this:

```
a<-rep(NA,200)
a[1]=1
a[2]=1
for(j in (3:200)){
  a[j]=a[a[j-1]]+a[j-a[j-1]]
}
b<-a/(c(1:200))
plot(b)
```